# Can you select and execute VimL / VimScript inside another file?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, functions

**Update**: It is possible with `'<,'>source`.

I figured it out right after writing this question, no need for the complicated **workaround**. I am gonna still let this question here and not delete it, maybe this will help someone out :)

## Question

**Is it possible to select the `VimL` part and execute it somehow?**

## Setup

`random.txt` file:

```
this is just a random text file
for example here are my notes
hello world

My VimL:
for i in range(3)
    echo i
endfor

some more useless text
end of this useless file
```

Note: This is just a **text file**, not a **vim file**

---

## My Idea

This is a workaround that works, but isn't too fancy:

`'<,'>w! /tmp/%:t.vim | source /tmp/%:t.vim`

Explanation:

- `'<,'>`: Is the selected text as a range
- `w!`: write command with `!` to overwrite in case file exists already
- `/tmp/%:t`: This is probably the most complicated thing, but here it is broken down:
- `/tmp`: dir to write the file into
- `%:t`: takes the current filename, but only the tail (`/home/user/Downloads/random.txt` -> `random.txt`)
- `.vim`: add a `.vim` extension. Not needed, but makes it more clear
- `source /tmp/%:t.vim`: finally source the `temporary file`

---

---

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you have a solution better post it like an answer to your own question. If you like it you can validate your own answer such that the question can rest. If other have idea they can post answer next to yours.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Oh I know you, you have commented on one of my other posts. And you are absolutely right, I should do that. From now on I am gonna do that, but do you want to do that for this question? I could then accept the answer immediately and you are gonna get `+12` rep. A win-win :)

Comment: I'm fine doing it but you can also accept your own answer after 1 day of delay and I would not get the point I didn't deserved ;-)

Comment: Okay your choice haha ^^ In my opinion you deserved it, because you help others out with comments, and comments don't bring you any `reputation` and it would be deserved to give you some `reputation` for that... But okay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Very simple command that works:

`'<,'>source`

Explanation:

- `'<,'>`: that is the **range**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759455/in-vim-visual-mode-why-does-the-command-start-with) or `:help '<`
- `source`: that is the **ex-command** to run VimL / Vimscript

### Simple way:

- Select text you want to run
- Press `:` in **normal mode**
- Type `source` or `so` for short